# We need a way to search the list of SE sites

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com

https://stackexchange.com/sites

The list is getting longer. Currently there's no way to search it other than find-in-page in a browser, and that doesn't allow you to find sites by keywords or domain (I want to search for "apple" to find apple.stackexchange.com, not "Ask Different"). Being able to search by question tags would also be useful.

Comment: Although I don't know any sane person who would search for "diy" - I think that a search feature should be something to be considered. Letting users quickly search the title and description of each site based on a couple keywords could help them easily find relevant sites out of an ever-growing list. Perhaps even display some snippets from the FAQ so users can quickly compare matching sites and decide which one to post on.

Comment: You are able to search by domain; there's a link for each. Once you're there you're back to manually looking of find on page.

Comment: @animuson bad example, I fixed it